# react native gcm android clicking on notification not opening the app

Tags: android, reactjs, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, react-native

I have this issue on simple app that should let the app receive a `GCM Notification` when receiving a request from the server. I was able to let the notification show up, but then clicking on the notification won't open the app?

Is there any functionality that I can do to make the `react-native-gcm-android` listen to notification clicks? Is this a known issue? Or is there any known fix to this?

We're specifically using this module `https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-gcm-android`,

Answer (score 0):

I am working with this package as well. 
What works for me was to remove `android:exported="false"` from

```
<receiver
  android:exported="false"
  android:name="com.oney.gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.oney.gcm.GCMReceiveNotification" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

under `AndroidManifest.xml`.

you will need to re-bundle the android app to see the effect.